# Поиск и замена при помощи регулярных выражений

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Суть задачи такая: найти нужные строки в текстовом документе, оставить в документе только эти строки. На ум приходит только вариант: произвести замену всех строк, которые не удовлетворяют условию на пустое значение, т.е. удалить их.

PS: Хотелось бы оставить только нужные строки за один проход в документе, не перегоняя во временный файл. Регулярные выражения использую в notepad++. Проблем с нахождением строк нет, проблема как удалить все те строки, которые не удовлетворяют условию.

Comment: ЯП угадывать будим?

Comment: Зачем? давайте не привязываться к языку программирования?.. Регулярные выражения это общий принцип анализа текстовой информации. Есть разные тонкости в использования их от .Net, Pyton, VC++ и т.д. Но все нормально конвертируется из одного языка в другой.
В качестве примера использования регулярного выражения, я предоставил notepad++. Не критично какая строка будет, вопрос стоит "как при помощи замены оставить в документе только те строки, которые удовлетворяют маске поиска?".
Если сложно с примером, то имеем такой текст:

Раз
Два
Три
Раз

Необходимо получить:
Раз
Раз

Comment: Есть большущий лог файл (пару десятков мегабайт) после работы программы. Знаю, что все ошибки которые возникают у приложения начинаются со строки "* Ошибка:". Составил достаточно сложное регулярное выражение, которое позволяет в лог файле выцыпить все строки, а также предыдущие две содержащие ключевые слова.

Необходимо оставить в файле информацию только о возникших ошибках, остальную часть лога убрать, т.к. программа в остальных вариантах отработала корректно.

PS: данный функционал можно еще применить в куче других случаев. Моя задача: Понять как можно избавиться от лишней информации

Comment: Обрабатывать "большущий лог файл" одним куском в памяти - не лучшее решение. Да и KISS :-) Построчная обработка будет намного проще, даже если накапливать предшествующие строки и сохранять только искомую + несколько нужных из накопителя.

Comment: Ну тут получается, что нужно найти нужную строку, и взять 2 строки перед ней... Хотя мне, как показалось, гораздо проще это делается поиском по тексту последовательности что-то вроде: "(?:\r\n)*(Раз строка)\(?:\r\n)(Два строка)(?:\r\n)(Три строка)". Для конкретного примера конечно это более сложная последовательность, но общая картинка регулярного выражения именно такая у меня получается... Ну и собственно стояла задача, как именно оставить только то, что удовлетворяет этой "маске", а остальное вычистить из файла.

Comment: @pincher1519, язык указывать надо. В разных ЯП разные диалекты регулярных выражений и разный набор поддерживаемых функций.  
Как пример: С# поддерживает обратную позиционную проверку переменной длины, а никакой другой движок регексов пока нет, а жаль.  

    (?<=\d+)
В С# сработает, а в других движках выдаст ошибку.

Comment: > Обрабатывать "большущий лог файл"

многое зависит от того как реализовано ведение лога в вашем приложении. может будет проще исправить / сконфигурировать чтоб ошибки писались в отдельный файл?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например так:

```
input = "\
str0\n\
str1\n\
str2\n\
str3\n\
str4\n";

re = /\n?^(?!(?:str1|str2|str3)$).*$\n?/gmi;

alert(input.replace(re, ''));
```

Comment: В принципе работает, если файл читать построчно. Если же представлять файл единой строкой с символами \r\n, то отрубает лишку.

Можешь расписать регулярку словесно?

как я понял: ищем начало строки (может ее не быть), следующую группу понять не могу, ищем все, что не следующая группа? и далее любые символы до возможного начала строки...

Answer (score 1):

> Зачем? давайте не привязываться к
> языку программирования?..

Но проблем)

```
var str = 'Раз Два Три Раз';
if(str.match(/(Два Три?\s)/gi))
{
    str = str.replace(/(Два Три?\s)/gi, '');
}

document.write(str); //Раз Раз
```

Comment: Ты не понял условия. Задача заменить все то, что не удовлетворяет маске регулярного выражения. Т.е. в приведенном примере, я знаю только то, что мне нужно оставить "Раз", что еще будет находиться во входящей информации мне не известно.

Answer (score 1):

В строке замены вставляйте соответствующий паттерн.

```
$&  Вставляет найденную подстроку.
$`  Вставляет часть строки, которая предшествует найденному вхождению.
$'  Вставляет часть строки, которая идет после найденного вхождения.
$n or $nn   Где n или nn - десятичные цифры, вставляет подстроку вхождения, запомненную n-й вложенной скобкой, если первый аргумент - объект RegExp.
```

Answer (score 1):

> Есть большущий лог файл (пару десятков
> мегабайт) после работы программы.
> Знаю, что все ошибки которые возникают
> у приложения начинаются со строки "*
> Ошибка:". Составил достаточно сложное
> регулярное выражение, которое
> позволяет в лог файле выцыпить все
> строки, а также предыдущие две
> содержащие ключевые слова.

$ cat mylog.log | ./[logtrunc.pl](http://logtrunc.pl) > newlog.log

$ cat ./[logtrunc.pl](http://logtrunc.pl)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use POSIX qw(locale_h);

setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "нужная_локаль");

my @lines;
while( <STDIN> )
{
    my $line = $_;
    if( $line =~ /\*Ошибка:/ ) # /^\*Ошибка:/
    {
        # здесь перебираем все предшествующие строки,
        # но никто не мешает ограничиться двумя:
        while( my $last = shift @lines )
        {
            print $last if $last =~ /условие для предшествующих строк/;
        }
        print $line;
        @lines = ();
    }
    else
    {
        push @lines, $line;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну вы сразу решаете задачу в лоб... С тем же успехом можно написать программу на c# в 10 строчек кода, которая переберет текстовый файл, загонит нужное в буфер и перезапишет исходный файл. Гораздо интереснее было для меня решить это одним/двумя регулярными выражениями.

Comment: Вот именно - я быстро, надёжно и эффективно конкретную решаю задачу, а не морщу лоб в поиске приключений непонятно зачем :) Тем более что практикой тыщу раз доказано, какие решения имеют смысл, а на какие время тратить жалко. Подход "разобрать мега-лог за один проход" как раз из последних.

P.S. Написание этого скриптика заняло 2 минуты. Вы ищете решение уже 8 часов. Думайте сами что лучше :)

Comment: не согласен, что задачу нужно решать в лоб. Я старался обойтись минимальным набором используемых инструментов. Остановился просто на текстовом редакторе, позволяющим открывать большие файлы и работать с поиском/заменой используя регулярные выражения.
да я и не просил собственно решать конкретную задачу. Мне нужна была информация о том, как построить регулярное выражение таким образом, чтобы в него попала информация такая, кроме как известная.

Answer (score 1):

А что мешает сделать так?

```
preg_replace("/.*?(your regex)/s", "$1", $text);
```

Я правда не тестировал, но если не сработает, то жесткая привязка к позиции точно поможет.

```
preg_replace("/\\G.*?(your regex)/s", "$1", $text);
```